# Auto hide alert messages at OpenCart

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am trying to auto hide the ajax alert messages in [OpenCart version 2.3.0.2](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/blog/info&blog_id=157) but I can't make it work correctly. I added the code below in my template's header file so I can hide the `.alert` div after 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 150);
}, 5000);
```

It works fine but only for the first alert triggered and I have to reload/refresh the page to make the hide script work again !

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your_code_here */ });` instead of `setTimeout`. This would ensure your code is called when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Again this will work only for the first alert message displayed. For Example when you add a product in cart, appearing an alert message saying "Success: You added the product bla bla bla ... to the cart ". and the message will hide after 5 secs. But after that if you add again a product in your cart with out first reload the page then the alert message will stay visible for ever !

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** You have to iterate on the array returned by `$(".alert")`.

[See this CodePen](http://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/NpbVVP)

Also, you should not use `setTimeout` to trigger the callback after DOM has loaded ; jQuery has `$(document).ready()` for that.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".alert").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  })
});
```

Comment: Again this will work only for the first alert message displayed. For Example when you add a product in cart, appearing an alert message saying "Success: You added the product bla bla bla ... to the cart ". and the message will hide after 5 secs. But after that if you add again a product in your cart with out first reload the page then the alert message will stay visible for ever !

Comment: Well, you need to bind an event handler to the event raised after the product is added !
I'm sure there's a way to turn this option off in your CMS. Either do that or raise an event from the *add product code* and bind an event handler to hide in your template file.
[See the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)